# Do we need to lock when using captured variable on a different thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

```
    public void GetData()
    {
        var locker = new object();
        var waiter = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        List<string> data = null;
        var thread= new Thread(() =>
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                data = GatherData();
            }
            waiter.Set();
        });
        thread.Start();

        waiter.WaitOne();
        lock (locker)
        {
            return data;
        }
    }
```

In this code, does the lock are useless ? Why ?

Comment: Since you block the thread that calls the `GetData` in `WaitOne` there is no reason to use a thread. And since there is no simultaneous access to `data` in your code, lock is not necessary.

Comment: Actually I use the thread in order to force GatherData to run in a STA Thread

Comment: But I don't see anywhere in your code `SetApartmentState` method. BTW: Why do you need this? is this some kind of [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=XY+Problem) ?

Comment: Any reason to be rude to people that tries to answer your question? I just needed further explanation for this *nonsense* code.

Comment: Sorry, don't wanted to be rude. I just tried to make the question as precise as possible, but seems I failed.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to have a memory barrier here.  Even if you knew that the read would happen after the write, if there were no barrier then the read would be allowed to read a cached value, or the write may not need to propagate its value from the cache.

That said, the ManualResetEvent that you're using is going to introduce a memory barrier when you wait on it, so you do not need to explicitly add another one.  The `lock` will also introduce a barrier, but since you already have one it is redundant in this instance.

Having said all of that, it's worth pointing out that it's rather pointless to create a new thread only to sit there and wait on it.  You may as well just run the code directly in the original thread, unless you've omitted code that would have that thread doing something else before waiting on the second thread.

Assuming you actually need the second thread to begin with, you should really look into using a `Task` here instead, as it will handle all synchronization of the results passed between tasks on your behalf.